# Must the vector multiplied by an orthogonal matrix be unique in order to get a unique resultant vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let's say I have a Hadamard matrix $W$ and a vector $y$ such that $W*x = y$ where $y$ is fixed and supposed to be known, and $x$ is a vector too. my question, how many possible vectors of $x$ can be exist in order to get the same result $y$?

For example, let's have $W = [1, -1; -1, 1]$ the vector $x$ can be either [1; 1] or [-1; -1] and the result of both multiplication is unique which is $y = 0$.

Is there a general rule for that ?

Comment: If $H\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$ is a Hadamard matrix, then it **must** satisfy $HH^T=nI,\;$ however $WW^T\ne nI.\;$ Further $\det(H)=\pm\sqrt{n^n}$ whereas $\det(W)=0.\;$ Your question seems to be about the solutions of a singular linear system $Wx=y.\;$  These can be expressed using an arbitrary vector $z$ and the Moore-Penrose inverse $W^+$  $$x=W^+y + (I-W^+W)z$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel $\ker(W) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Wx = 0\}$ is always a vector space. That means, if $Wx = 0$ has a solution that is different from $x = 0$, you will automatically have infinitely many solutions. Indeed, If $x$ solves $Wx = 0$, then also $W(\lambda x) = \lambda Wx = 0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Likewise, if $x$ is a solution of $Wx = y$, then $x' = x+v$ is also a solution for all $v \in \ker(W)$. So it all depends on the dimension of $\ker(W)$. If $\ker(W) = \{0\}$, then the solution is unique.

Comment: must it be $Wx = 0$ ? I mean what's about if we want it to be a vector different to zeros ? for example a vector include $1$ and $-1$ values

Comment: @Fatima_Ali Didn't I write what happens if $y \neq 0$ in the second part of the answer (after "Likewise")? I am happy to clarify if it is not clear.

Comment: OK .. thank you so much

Comment: I got it,  but in that case, it's not possible to get $x$ based on $y$, right ?

Comment: @Fatima_Ali It's not always possible, it depends on the matrix $W$. If the matrix is quadratic and $\ker(W) = \{0\}$, then it is always possible and the solution is unique. If you want to know how to solve such problems, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination or post a new question.